# Unit test HttpPost Create action of MVC4 controller

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4

Can somebody please guide me how to write Unit test in VS 2012 unit test project to the httppost create action?

My action looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Organization obj)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            OrganizationRepo.Create(obj);
            UnitOfWork.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("List");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

After successfully creating an object in database, I am not sure what to assert in unit tests..

It would be great if you can suggest some negative tests also...

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> After successfully creating an object in database, I am not sure what to assert in unit tests

You should assert that the controller action redirected to the `List` action, i.e. the `ActionResult` returned is a `RedirectToRouteResult`.

> It would be great if you can suggest some negative tests also

In this case you could assert that no object has been created and the same `Create` view was rendered, i.e. the returned `ActionResult` is a `ViewResult`.